# Skype for Linux Alpha Wingpanel Indicator

Tags: wingpanel, skype

Is there any way I can change the Skype for Linux Alpha wingpanel indicator to match the default theme?

Currently it's green:

[image]

GTK: Arc
Icon theme: ElementaryPlus
elementary OS Loki

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is a mod for this on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503267/change-skype-tray-icon). It allows you to use any icons you want, but the package listed to download is a monochrome that goes well with elementary.

Comment: Thanks for responding, and sorry for the late reply. That link didn't seem to work for me, though. After `sudo dpkg -i sni-qt_0.2.6-0ubuntu1_i386-modified.deb` I get:

`package sni-qt:i386 0.2.6-0ubuntu1 cannot be configured because sni-qt:amd64 is at a different version (0.2.8-0~81~ubuntu16.04.1)
`

Comment: Yes, this uses a slightly older sni_qt. It installed fine for me because I do not have sni-qt:amd installed. I only have the 32bit version installed. Skype works fine for me without the 64bit sni-qt, but maybe something else you have installed uses it. You could try downgrading the 64bit version but it could affect whatever app is using it, if that app requires the newest version of sni-qt. If you want to try use sudo dpkg -i on this deb https://ftp.fau.de/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sni-qt/sni-qt_0.2.6-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, or you would have to completly disable the icon or edit the icon file itself because i don't think skype has support for that stuff.